# MAC addresses on a machine / filtering out the MAC addresses of plug and play devices

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, mac-address, plug-and-play

I have the following code which runs through and populates a character array with up to 3 WiFi and Ethernet adapter MAC addresses on a Windows machine:

```
IP_ADAPTER_INFO *info = NULL, *pos;
DWORD size = 0;
if (GetAdaptersInfo(info, &size) != ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW)
    return;
info = (IP_ADAPTER_INFO *)malloc(size);
if (GetAdaptersInfo(info, &size) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    return;
char addresses[1024];
char buffer[1024];
memset(addresses, 0, sizeof(addresses));
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
int recordedAddresses = 0;
for (pos = info; pos != NULL; pos = pos->Next) {
    if (pos->Type != IF_TYPE_IEEE80211 && pos->Type != MIB_IF_TYPE_ETHERNET)
        continue;
    if (recordedAddresses > 0)
        strcat_s<sizeof(addresses)>(addresses, " ");
    for (int i = 0; i < pos->AddressLength; i++) {
        sprintf_s<sizeof(buffer)>(buffer, i == 0 ? "%2.2x" : ":%2.2x", pos->Address[i]);
        strcat_s<sizeof(addresses)>(addresses, buffer);
    }
    recordedAddresses++;
    if (recordedAddresses >= 3)
        break;
}
free(info);
// The array called 'addresses' now contains something like this: a0:b1:c2:d3:e4:f5 0a:1b:2c:3d:4e:5f 00:01:02:03:04:05
```

How can I detect if any of these `IP_ADAPTER_INFO` structures refer to plug and play devices? Is there a standard way of doing this? I have been searching for a solution. Ideally, I wish to filter out Plug-and-Play WiFi dongles from my list of `addresses`, the type of dongles that have a USB interface and allow you to get a WiFi connection running on your Windows machine via USB dongle (if possible).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES NOT IP_ADAPTER_INFO Struct.

Look specifically for PhysicalAddress and interate through the addresses.

Comment: How is that going to filter out plug-and-play WiFi adapters like this one? https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01MTLBWXH?psc=1

Comment: Each plug and play device has to register as a usb device. Find its corresponding device id and seperate from the rest of the usbs installed. Do you have physical access to this device?

Comment: How do you know what devices are USB devices?

Comment: You can tell which devices are USB by 3 ways. SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\DeviceClasses\\{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b} Key:DEVINTERFACE_DISK

SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\DeviceClasses\\{53F5630D-B6BF-11D0-94F2-00A0C91EFB8B}\\Control Key:DEVINTERFACE_VOLUME 

SYSTEM\\MountedDevices\\DosDev\ Key: USBSTOR
You will want to check this string specifically to separate from fixed devices in listings. This is the most evident. If you grab your mac address from your current function you can match its ClassID for the USB device.
\\??\\STORAGE#RemovableMedia#

Comment: Each time a PNP device is registered it is placed into these keys.

Comment: I am hoping there may be an API for this instead of using the registry. From my experience, the registry is much easier to spoof.