# Displaying the & character in SysLink control

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, text, controls

I have a *SysLink* control in a Win32 project's Dialog. I am trying to show the `&` character in it. For example:

```
SetWindowText(hyperlink, _T("<a>https://www.stackoverflow/?a=1&b=2</a>"));
```

`hyperlink` is the handle to my *SysLink* control.

The problem is that `&` does not show in the text. Instead, what I see is this:

> https://www.stackoverflow/?a=1b=2

How can I make this control display the `&` symbol?

Comment: Escape it as `&&` perhaps?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That worked, thank you. How did you know to double-ampersand?

Comment: I don't know. I just knew!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If you're in the mood, I have an unrelated question you might have come across or have the knowledge on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43786697/mac-addresses-on-a-machine-filtering-out-the-mac-addresses-of-plug-and-play-de Just waiting for the 10 minute cool-down to mark your answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the ampersand as `&&`. Otherwise it is interpreted as indicating an accelerator character.

Answer (score 3):

The ampersand character is interpreted as the prefix to a shortcut key by default. If you don't want the SysLink control to interpret the ampersand character, pass the `LWS_NOPREFIX` [SysLink Control Style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc136543.aspx) when [creating the SysLink control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298379.aspx).

While the ampersand character *can* be escaped (by prefixing it with another ampersand character), it does change the control contents. This is usually not intended when the SysLink control renders markup.